# Oxford comma only for three or more authors, but not for exactly two authors

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, punctuation

I want to insert the Oxford Comma only if an entry has 3 or more authors, but not if the entry has exactly two authors.

e.g.

> A and B (1999) [NO COMMA]
>
> A, B, and C (1999) [COMMA before C]

I tried

```
author = "A and Firstname { B,} and C"
```

in the bib entry itself. This works for citation call-outs, but then two commas appear in the formatted bibliographic entry.

I use the `aea` bibliography style, which is available online [here](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/policies/templates). As you can probably guess by now, this bibliography style is set up to always insert a comma between `penultimate_author` and `and final_author` -- even if an entry has *exactly two* authors. Is there a way to adjust this bibliography style such that the Oxford comma gets inserted only if an entry has *three or more* authors?

For the sake of completeness, here's the function `format.names` from the `aea` bibliography style:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
  { namesleft #0 > }
    { nameptr #1 = 
        {   s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ 't := }
        {   s nameptr "{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't := }
        if$
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
          { ", " * t * }
          { t "others" =
            { ", et~al." * }
            { " and " * t * }
            if$
          }
          if$
        }
        't
        if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
    while$
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A terminological convention up-front: if the list of surnames contains exactly 2 items, the comma that's inserted between `first_surname` and `and second_surname` should *not* be called an "Oxford comma". Incidentally, why are you employing the `aea` bibliography style if you don't like some of its formatting settings?

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Make a copy of `aea.bst` and call the copy, say, `aea-oxford.bst`.
- Open the file `aea-oxford.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the file, locate the function `format.names`. Basically, that's the function whose code you displayed in your query.
- In this function, replace the three lines

  ```
    { t "others" =
      { ", et~al." * }
      { ", and " * t * }
  ```

  with the following seven lines:

  ```
        { numnames #2 >
            { "," * }
            'skip$
          if$
          t "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * t * }
  ```

  The first part of the new code consists of a test to check if the total number of surnames is *greater than 2*. If yes, insert a comma; if no, do nothing. In the second part (which only ever gets executed if there are *two or more* surnames, one of which may be the string "others"), a plain "and" is inserted if the second surname is "real", i.e., doesn't consist of the string "others".
- Store the file `aea-oxford.bst` in the directory where your main tex file is located.
- In the main tex file, change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `aea` to `aea-oxford`. Then, perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, and LaTeX once more -- to fully propagate all changes.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and screenshot; I've highlighted in yellow the two changes wrought in `aea-oxford.bst`:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{a, author = "A", title  = "Thoughts", year   = 3001, } 
@misc{ab, author = "A and B", title  = "Thoughts", year   = 3002, }
@misc{abc, author = "A and B and C", title  = "Thoughts", year   = 3003, }
@misc{abcd, author = "A and B and C and D", title  = "Thoughts", year   = 3004, }
@misc{abcde, author = "A and others", title  = "Thoughts", year   = 3005, }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aea-oxford}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{a}, \cite{ab}, \cite{abc}, \cite{abcd}, \cite{abcde}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

Just for comparison, here's the output of the same MWE if the unmodified `aea` bibliography style were used -- note the two additional commas:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Mico! In the text, I would also like to have A,B, and C (3003). Which part of the code refers to the names in the text?

Comment: @masterplan18 - Find the function `format.names.label.short`; in that function, find the line that says `{ t "others" =`. Inbetween `{` and `t`,  insert the same new instructions as in the answer shown above, i.e., `numnames #2 >  { "," * }  'skip$  if$`.

Comment: Thank you again, Mico! Saved me a lot of time.