# Adding the Oxford comma to bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, punctuation

I am aware of several [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373313/how-do-i-add-oxford-serial-comma-with-dcu-bibliography-style) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454205/oxford-comma-only-for-three-or-more-authors-but-not-for-exactly-two-authors) on this topic, but have not been able to adapt these solutions for the following problem.

I am using the `econ-econometrica.bst` bibliography style, available [here](https://github.com/ShiroTakeda/econ-bst/blob/master/customization/econ-econometrica.bst), because it implements the [certified random order](https://doi.org/10.1257/aer.20161492) for authors. However, for in-text citations that list all authors given by the `\cite*` command in `natbib`, I am unable to get the Oxford comma to appear.

For example, I would like the in-text citation to read "A, B, and C (yyyy)" rather than "A, B and C (yyyy)."

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The `econ-econometrica` bibliography style uses Oxford commas in the formatted bibliographic entries, but not in the citation call-outs in case the `natbib` package is loaded with the option `longnamesfirst`. This would appear to be an oversight on the part of bib style file's author, Shiro Takeda Have you considered contacting the author on their GitHub page about this?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for responding! Just trying to understand your comment: I'm not loading the option `longnamesfirst` with the `natbib` package, but rather just calling `\cite*` sometimes. How are the two issues related (e.g., would having the issue resolved for the `longnamesfirst` option also resolve it for the `\cite*` command)?

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion. A citation call-out can be told to use the full list of authors with either `\cite[x]*` or `longnamesfirst` (well, just for the first time a piece with more than 2 authors is cited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having poked through more lines of `.bst` files than I ever wanted, here is a simple fix that I found:

1. Search for the following in `econ-econometrica.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {bst.cite.ands}
{ " and " }
```

2. Replace it with this:

```
FUNCTION {bst.cite.ands}
{ ", and " }
```

Hope this [helps any future seekers of truth](https://xkcd.com/979/).